# Build a service for XMPP - ANDROID

Tags: android, service, xmpp

I'm writing an message application which use XMPP protocol to communicate. 
To communicate I'm using Smack library. Establish connection, receive and 
send messages I've done already (at least tested).

My question is how to properly setup the running service for connection?
I'm mean if it should be service in different thread? And how to communicate
with it? To receive the messages from service I can use broadcast receiver,
but how to send it?

I found couple examples, but most of them are chat apps, which keeps xmpp
connection in main classes.

Maybe I'm just thinking wrong and it should be done in other way.

Thanks and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a singleton class and use that for your application and you will use broadcast reveicer to send message and presence to your main screen because in smack you have to use the same connection through out your application.